# Is Core Data Lightweight Migration, on Lion, not saving a backup file?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Previously, when you did a lightweight migration, core data created a backup file in the same folder like ~yourFile. But using Lion, I can't find this backup file. Is the file hided somewhere? I did look the documentation, but without success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ˜file is no more automatically created. So the solution I found is to create the file programatically.
So, I'm posting my solution

```
// Determine if a migration is needed
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:url error:&error];
NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectModel];
BOOL pscCompatibile = [destinationModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

// if migration is needed, copy the file appending OLD to the original name
if (pscCompatibile == 0) {
    NSLog(@"doing migration");

    NSURL *urlOld = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"AudioStManDataOLD"]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:url toURL:urlOld error:&error];
}
```

tx
Mario